# Combining two bash script and using a menu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

I have two scripts, one that is used on a folder with csv files and another on a folder with .tar.gz files. In the second script, I first unzip the files before doing anything with them. Now I want to combine both scripts into one script where a user can specify which folder he/she wants to work with. When the script is run, the user has two options, to either use folderA or folderB. Sort of like a menu.

#### ScriptA

```
#!/bin/bash
FOLDER=/path/to/folder
DATE_LOG=`date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"`
LOG_FILE=/home/kamil/Desktop/Script/log_$DATE_LOG.txt


# Getting the pattern and headers of files from FOLDER
cd "$FOLDER"
    for file in *.csv; do
    echo -n "${file}" "|" | sed -r 's/(.*)_[0-9]{8}_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].csv/\1/'
        head -1 "$file"
    done | tee $LOG_FILE
```

#### ScriptB

```
#!/bin/bash
FOLDER_HISTO=/path/to/folder/WithTAR.GZ
DATE_LOG=`date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"`
LOG_FILE=/home/kamil/Desktop/Script/log_$DATE_LOG.txt


# Getting the pattern and headers of files from FOLDER_HISTO
cd "$FOLDER_HISTO"
    for zip_file in *.tar.gz; do
    file=`tar -xvf $zip_file`
    echo -n "${file}" "|" | sed -r 's/(.*)_[0-9]{8}_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].csv/\1/'
        head -1 "$file"
    done | tee $LOG_FILE
```

Comment: The second script assigns the variable `FOLDER_HISTO`, but then uses `$FOLDER`. Is that a copying error?

Comment: It also uses a variable `$FICHIER_LOG` that wasn't set.

Comment: Yes copying error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the standard CLI way to make a menu is `select`:

```
select response in "Folder 1" "Folder 2"
do
    case $response in
        "Folder 1") cd folder1; /path/to/ScriptA.sh; exit ;;
        "Folder 2") cd folder2; /path/to/ScriptB.sh; exit ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Yes, but i want only one script not two separate scripts.

Comment: @musty So? Replace `/path/to/ScriptA.sh` with the commands in the first script and `/path/to/ScriptB.sh` with the commands in the second script.

Answer (score 1):

The scripts are so similar, I would combine them into one script. It would take two arguments: an option `-tar` or `-csv` to indicate how the files should be expanded, and a directory name for where to `cd` to.

```
MODE=$1
FOLDER=$2
DATE_LOG=`date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"`
LOG_FILE=/home/kamil/Desktop/Script/log_$DATE_LOG.txt

case "$mode" in 
    -tar) SUFFIX=tar.gz
          CMD="tar -xvf" 
        ;;
    -csv) SUFFIX=csv
          CMD="cat" 
        ;;
    *) echo Invalid mode "$mode" >&2; exit 1 ;;
esac

if ! cd "$FOLDER"
then echo "Bad folder $FOLDER" >&2
     exit 1
fi
for file in *.SUFFIX; do
    contents=`$CMD $file`
    echo -n "$contents" "|" | sed -r 's/(.*)_[0-9]{8}_[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].csv/\1/'
    head -1 "$contents"
done | tee $LOG_FILE
```

The stuff you're doing in the `for` loop doesn't look right, I suspect that's more copying errors. Hopefully you'll be able to figure out how to fit what you're actually doing into the above structure. The general idea is to find all the places where the two scripts differ, and put them into variables that are set in the `case` statement. You might not be able to do everything with simple variable substitutions like I did -- you might need an `if` statement as well.

This is called the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle.

If the folders are always the same depending on the mode, you could put the `FOLDER` assignment into the `case` statement, instead of requiring it on the command line. You could also replace the command-line option with a menu as in muru's answer.